Does Shiva promote total caste discrimination in housing and rituals?
Kamika Agama Purva Pada:
1.80

For the brahmins, tripundra should be with a length of 6 angulas.... For the women, it should be in one angula. People of other castes (अन्यजातिस्तु-children of higher varna father and lower varna mother) should refrain from applying the tripundra.

This agama apparently contains the words of Shiva himself. Here Shiva is supposedly saying different jatis and sexes will apply the forehead marks in different ways - and some can't even apply these marks.
3.92

The exact rules for the wearing of sacred thread laid down for the mixed castes and others (अनुलोमादि) should be consulted well and decided as to whether they could or could not wear the sacred thread.

For children of inter-caste marriages this means either 1) there are different rituals or 2) potentially they cannot wear the sacred thread at all.
11.21-25

The bhautika-bhumi is fit for the sudras. The paisaca-bhumi, asura-bhumi and the rakshasa-bhumi are suitable for the people of the last and lowest caste (chandalas).
For the people of mixed caste, the ground should be selected according to the natural formation and qualities of the land.

This means different jatis including varna sankara jatis should be housed on different types of soil.
30.15

The dwelling place for the vaisyas may be in all directions
around the village and that for the sudras is to be in the
south-west. The dwelling place for the people of chandalas and for the hired
laborers is to be in the north side of the burial ground.

This again shows that different jatis should have different locations in the village.
45.10

The building which is provided with various levels floors furnished with..... This is fit for all the four varieties of the anuloma group.

Meaning children of inter-caste marriages should live in specific type of houses.
.
There are many more such verses. So does Shiva want humans to promote total caste discrimination in housing and rituals?

Exactly how is the tilak verse even casteist that's just general injunction. Yes different communities do live on different lands, because each follow there own rules and the mixing of communities could lead to pollution.

Obviously because it specifies restrictions for anulom (intercaste) people @Haridasa ... Thanks for exposing yourself

No I am not exposing myself and most of the HSE members here usually view in favor of keeping communities separate at least in regards to those times. We're simply upfront with truth which liberal Hindus want to hide by acting like it isn't a big deal or what not.
